# How to put together Clean architecture and IHostingStartup and IConfiguration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, clean-architecture

Trying to implement clean architecture in a new project, but with some restrictions: I want to loose dependencies as much as possible.

Basic:

Solution has several projects:

- `WebApi`
- `UseCases` (referenced by `WebApi`, implements business logic)
- `Gateway` (referenced by `UseCases`, provides repository interfaces to `UseCases`)
- `DataAccess.EfCore` (referenced by `Gateway`, implements access to MSSQL)
- `Domain.Core` (Domain model is here)

What is desired and what problems are solved and still here:
- All projects has `IHostingStartup` implementations where they are configure themselves: `UseCases` registering some behaviours, `Gateway` - it's interfaces, `EfCore` - configuring `DbContext` and registering it.

Looks fine. Almost. There two architectural problems for now:

1. Configuring ASP.NET Core Identity. Usually it is done in the `WebApi` project, but in this case I have to reference `EfCore` project to be able to write this:

`services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();`

class "`MyDbContext`" is declared in `EfCore` project, so this one line has settings from two worlds:

- AddIdentity() : WebApi world
- AddEntityFrameworkStores() : DataAccess world (because "MyDbContext" class is belong to it)

If I put Identity configuration into the `DataAccess` - then I have to configure such things as Identity lockout settings and Login/AccessDenied pages in the `DataAccess` what is also wrong and what should not be done there.
Is it possible to split the configuration, so `DataAccess.EfCore` will just register `DbContext` store for identity and `WebApi` is configuring lockouts and other stuff?

2. I'm using user secrets to store connection strings. How to pass it to the `IHostingStartup` implementation to configure `DbContext`? Method signature is allowing to work with `IWebHostBuilder` builder only, so I'm stuck here also.

Any ideas, help, experience?

UPD:
Or, almost forgot about 3rd problem:

3. When I'm running the app at first time - I want to seed some data into the DB. And the problem here is to seed the `IdentityUser` entities as they should be added through `UserService` (password hashing etc), but at the same time I want to do it in the `DataAccess.EfCore` project: I'm using `FluentAPI` to configure the models and seeding the data with "`HasData`" method. So any idea here would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

if you refer with "Clean Architecture" to Uncle Bobs article and book (https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) then your project setup needs a little cleanup.

In Clean Architecture Gateways depend on use cases, not the other way round. One key principle in this architecture is "inversion of control": you define interfaces in the inner circles and keep the implementations details (like EF, DbContext and other frameworks) in the outer circles.

The wiring of the interfaces and implementations happens in the "main component" - which in asp.net core would be the startup class.

More details on implementing Clean Architecture (e.g. in Asp.Net) you can find in my blog series: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture/